# Modifying "Const Char Pointers" in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, pass-by-reference

I am doing a program to test swapping couple of things by reference.
I managed to get the first two functions in my code to work but can't get to change the `char *` in the third function.

I think the problem is that it's a constant and only valid to `read-only` 
that's what the error is telling me but How to be able to work with it in this way?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapping(int &x, int &y) 
{
    int temp =x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;

}

void swapping(float &x, float &y)
{
    float temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;

} 


void swapping(const char *&x,const char *&y) 
{

    int help = *x;
    (*x)=(*y);
    (*y)=help;

} // swap char pointers



int main(void) {
    int a = 7, b = 15;
    float x = 3.5, y = 9.2;

    const char *str1 = "One";
    const char *str2 = "Two";



    cout << "a=" << a << ", b=" << b << endl;
    cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y << endl;
    cout << "str1=" << str1 << ", str2=" << str2 << endl;

    swapping(a, b);
    swapping(x, y);
    swapping(str1, str2);

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "a=" << a << ", b=" << b << endl;
    cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y << endl;
    cout << "str1=" << str1 << ", str2=" << str2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `const char*` overloads should look exactly like you other overloads.  Give that a try.

Comment: didn't work, you mean to change the arguments type to `int` or `float`

Comment: Just like you did `int temp =x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;` for `int`'s, you should be using `const char* temp =x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;` for `const char *`'s.

Comment: thank! but can you explain why that happened?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica (the sooner the better) Bishoy, what happened (depending on your machine x86_64, etc..) is `sizeof (int)` is only 1/2 the `sizeof(a_pointer)`, (generally `int` is 4-bytes and `a_pointer` is 8-bytes on 64-bit systems). When you use `int help = *x;` (should be just `x`, not `*x` a `char`), `help` isn't large enough to hold the complete address, so things go off the rails at that point in your `str1`, `str2` pointer swap. Also, enable compiler warnings and do not accept code until it compile without warning (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments:

```
void swapping(const char*& x, const char*& y)
{
    auto t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
}
```

Now you should consider to use a template:

```
template<typename Type>
void swapping(Type& a, Type& b)
{
    auto t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```